# How do I display my meta_key value in my wp_query() loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have found a lot of ways to filter posts using meta values, but I can't seem how to simply display them. I have created a custom post type with meta fields. I have also made my wp_query() filter by a specific meta value. But I can't find the way to simply display a meta value in a specific place.

```
<?php
  // WP_Query arguments
            $args = array(
                'p'                      => 'products',
                'post_type'              => array( 'products' ),
                'order'                  => 'ASC',
                'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
                'meta_key'  => 'custom_product_position',
            );

            // The Query
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // The Loop
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                   echo the_title();
                   echo get_the_content();
                }
            } else {
                // no posts found
            }

            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
?>
```

I would like to add inside my loop echo (meta value of custom_product_position) how would I do this? meta_value('custom_product_position') does not work.

This seems like a super easy question to solve, but I can't figure out how to search for the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use `get_post_meta`, here is the link to the documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

And here is your code:

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'key_1', true );
// Check if the custom field has a value.
if ( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) {
    echo $key_1_value;
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!